# What is the best angle to throw the Brothers at?

Tags: fish-out-of-water

In *Fish Out of Water*, what is the best method or angle to throw the Brothers (the fish who splits into a few other fish)? I've found through trial and error some decent throwing angles for some of the other fish, but have yet to find one that works well to get much distance or skips in.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah those guys are pretty much worthless:( I found if I line them up low with the mountain peak and flick them straight, gradually using all boosts I can usually get 90-120 skips out of them.